# Google direction api skipping information about small turns

Tags: java, php, android, google-maps

Google direction api skipping  information about small turns .

[for example following information about this  turn is skipping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18R0d.png)

i am using this code 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=30.6545095,76.8163058&destination=paras%20,downtown%20zirakpur&key=mykey&optimize:true

```
{
   "geocoded_waypoints" : [
      {
         "geocoder_status" : "OK",
         "place_id" : "ChIJb4RRbjbrDzkRJ6rnllrRaHo",
         "types" : [ "political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1" ]
      },
      {
         "geocoder_status" : "OK",
         "partial_match" : true,
         "place_id" : "ChIJBQuF-jDrDzkR49h1v8UzbpM",
         "types" : [ "premise" ]
      }
   ],
   "routes" : [
      {
         "bounds" : {
            "northeast" : {
               "lat" : 30.6545368,
               "lng" : 76.8166615
            },
            "southwest" : {
               "lat" : 30.6482275,
               "lng" : 76.8120363
            }
         },
         "copyrights" : "Map data ©2016 Google",
         "legs" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "1.4 km",
                  "value" : 1415
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "6 mins",
                  "value" : 371
               },
               "end_address" : "Paras Down Town Square mall, Green Enclave Rd, Badal Colony, Zirakpur, Punjab 140603, India",
               "end_location" : {
                  "lat" : 30.6483638,
                  "lng" : 76.8166615
               },
               "start_address" : "Utrathiya, Zirakpur, Punjab, India",
               "start_location" : {
                  "lat" : 30.6545368,
                  "lng" : 76.8162957
               },
               "steps" : [
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0.2 km",
                        "value" : 153
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 min",
                        "value" : 25
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 30.6535831,
                        "lng" : 76.8151584
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Head \u003cb\u003esouthwest\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "{ebzD{dzsM@DDJNTfDzD"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 30.6545368,
                        "lng" : 76.8162957
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0.2 km",
                        "value" : 204
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 min",
                        "value" : 76
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 30.6522304,
                        "lng" : 76.8165913
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eleft\u003c/b\u003e toward \u003cb\u003eNH5\u003c/b\u003e/\u003cb\u003eNH7\u003c/b\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003ePass by Patanjali Retail Store (on the left)\u003c/div\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "{_bzDw}ysMn@s@hAkA`@c@NQ~AeB@A"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 30.6535831,
                        "lng" : 76.8151584
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0.5 km",
                        "value" : 547
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 min",
                        "value" : 81
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 30.6492641,
                        "lng" : 76.8120363
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eright\u003c/b\u003e at Anoopam Dhaba onto \u003cb\u003eNH5\u003c/b\u003e/\u003cb\u003eNH7\u003c/b\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003ePass by Gurdwara Singh Sabha (on the right)\u003c/div\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-right",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "mwazDufzsMz@|Az@zA\\h@bAjBHL^n@zB`Eb@z@jArB`@t@`@p@\\d@"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 30.6522304,
                        "lng" : 76.8165913
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0.1 km",
                        "value" : 137
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 min",
                        "value" : 41
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 30.6482275,
                        "lng" : 76.8128078
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eleft\u003c/b\u003e at Bir Real Estates, Zirakpur, Punjab onto \u003cb\u003eLohgarh Rd\u003c/b\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003ePass by Web Design Courses In Zirakpur (on the right)\u003c/div\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "{dazDgjysMfBiAdBoA"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 30.6492641,
                        "lng" : 76.8120363
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0.4 km",
                        "value" : 374
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "2 mins",
                        "value" : 148
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 30.6483638,
                        "lng" : 76.8166615
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eleft\u003c/b\u003e at Garg Property Consultant onto \u003cb\u003eGreen Enclave Rd\u003c/b\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003ePass by Happy Electronics (on the left)\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003eDestination will be on the right\u003c/div\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "m~`zDaoysM?A_@s@?SAoE@{C@eA?qA@y@?wA@a@"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 30.6482275,
                        "lng" : 76.8128078
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  }
               ],
               "traffic_speed_entry" : [],
               "via_waypoint" : []
            }
         ],
         "overview_polyline" : {
            "points" : "{ebzD{dzsMFPvDpEjDuD`BgBvBxDjCrElGfL~@vAlEyC_@u@AcFDmJ@yB"
         },
         "summary" : "NH5/NH7 and Green Enclave Rd",
         "warnings" : [],
         "waypoint_order" : []
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

So how this problem can be solve?

Comment: Will Google Maps itself show the turn in its turn by turn list? Maybe this is just a crossing you pass straight.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a data issue.

In this case you can use the "Report a problem" link on the bottom right corner of the maps.google.com.

https://support.google.com/maps/answer/162873

You can also try to use mapmaker.google.com to make the edits yourself and it will be reviewed by the community. You can read about the Map Maker tool here
https://support.google.com/mapmaker#topic=3180752

The URL for your route in Map Maker is

https://mapmaker.google.com/mapmaker?saddr=30.6545095,76.8163058&daddr=paras,+downtown+zirakpur&dirflg=d&gw=56&ll=30.655489,76.818573&spn=0.005002,0.008465&z=17&lyt=large_map_v3

Hope it helps!